# SQL-how to get the count of number substrings in a string in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named `Garden`.

In the `Garden` table there is column named `Fruit` with thousands of rows
and each row of `Fruit` has comma seperated values like `Apple`, `Banana`, `Pear`  and so on.

I want the get the count of the number fruits in each row in `Fruit` column
like if first row has `Apple`, `Banana`, `Pear`, then the count should return 3.

How to write a sql query for it.

I tried using regex but its not working.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Storing records as comma separated values in tables is a bad practice. Avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
select length(Fruit) - length(replace(Fruit, ',', '')) + 1 from Garden
```

This part `len(Fruit) - len(replace(Fruit, ',', ''))` returns how many commas are in your string and there are always one item more than commas, so we need to add 1.

Comment: I am ORACLE DBMS.Thanks for your reply.It is giving error as ORA-00904: "LEN": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @AbhinayKumar In Oracle the function is called `LENGTH`. Updated my answer and it will work now.

Comment: @AbhinayKumar You should accept the answer then (green tick below the score of an answer). And upvote optionally.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Oracle database then you can use **REGEXP_COUNT** regular expression.Find the below example:-

```
     create table garden( fruit varchar2(1000));

     insert into garden VALUES('apple,bananan,pear');
     insert into garden VALUES('orange,bananan');
     insert into garden VALUES('apple,bananan,pear,orange');

     select * from garden;

     output:-

     FRUIT
     ------------------
     apple,bananan,pear
     orange,bananan
     apple,bananan,pear,orange
```

Now you can use below query to get the count.

`select REGEXP_COUNT(Fruit, ',')+1 as fruit_count from garden;`

Comment: I think this is the better solution for Oracle.